# Disallow all status changes in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin

Is there a way to ask Pidgin to not touch the "status" of any of my accounts, ever? I use different statuses at work vs my personal account, but pidgin is always mixing and matching them... I've tried disabling everything in `Preferences > Status / Idle`, but to no avail.

I'm using Pidgin 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin stored your status in ~/.purple/status.xml. You can delete it if you want to.

Comment: It just comes right back...

Comment: You can try this: chose the status box, chose **New status...**, **Use a different status for some account**. stick account what you want, add your status and click Use.